# How to calculate MAPE for Training/Test set in application of Neural Network in MATLAB efficiently?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, matlab

I've been using MATLAB for my time series dataset (for an electricity dataset) as a part of my course. It consists of 40,000+ samples. After the formation of neural network, I wanted to test its accuracy. I've been curious more on MAPE(mean absolute percentage error) and RMS(Root Mean Square) errors. To calculate them, I've used following lines of code.

```
mape_res = zeros(N_TRAIN);
mse_res = zeros(N_TRAIN);
for i_train = 1:N_TRAIN
  Inp = inputs_consumption(i_train );
  Actual_Output = targets_consumption( i_train + 1 );
  Observed_Output = sim( ann, Inp );

  mape_res(i_train) = abs(Observed_Output - Actual_Output)/Actual_Output;
  mse_res(i_train) = Observed_Output - Actual_Output;

end

mape = sum(mape_res)/N_TRAIN;
mse = sum(power(mse_res,2))/N_TRAIN;
sprintf( 'The MSE on training is %g', mse )
sprintf( 'The MAPE on training is %g', mape )
```

The problem with above coding is that, for a large dataset(40K samples), it takes almost 15 minutes to iterate through all those loops and it's quite a long waiting for getting result for the error rate; Isn't there any other efficient way to calculate them?

Comment: What does profiler analysis say? Where is the critical section of code?

Answer (score 3):

You could always do a rolling average that gets updated each iteration, as follows:

```
mape_res = abs(Observed_Output - Actual_Output) / Actual_Output;
mse_res  = Observed_Output - Actual_Output;

alpha = 1 / i_train;
mape = mape * (1 - alpha) + mape_res * alpha;
mse  = mes * (1 - alpha) + power(mse_res,2) * alpha;
```

Then you could either display the resulting values each iteration, use them for stopping criteria if the desired error rate is reached, or both.  This also has the added benefit of not requiring the initialization and population of the mape_res and mse_res vectors unless they happen to be needed elsewhere...

Edit: Do make sure to initialize the mape and mse values to zero prior to entering the for loop :)

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply but I want to determine the error rates after the network has been fully trained; and don't intent to use the error rates for stopping criteria.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll just have to wait until the loop completes.  At least this way, you remove the requirement for allocation and population of vectors, thus reducing your memory requirements.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have access to the Parallel Processing Toolbox for Matlab.  That's what we currently use to run large datasets through our neural networks at the office -- might be worth checking out if you have/can afford it...

Comment: Just following up with you on this -- did this sufficiently answer your question?